Using a JSON to complete a dataframe
I have a JSON like this:
people = {
   'jon' : { 'age' : 20 } ,
   'peter' : { 'age' : 30 } 
}

And I have a datframe indexed by name:




city
age




jon
foo
NaN


peter
foo
NaN



What is the best way to populate the age in my dataframe using the JSON ?
Many thanks in advance !
I have tried something like this,
for line in ['jon','peter']:
    df.at[line,'age'] = people[line]['age']

Which was really a wild try. There must be something much more obvious

You can load the dictionary in a dataframe and use combine first to fill the missing values using the values from the new dataframe. The T is to transpose the new dataframe to have the names(jon, peter) as index and age as a column.
Add [df.columns] at the end if you want to retain the position of the columns.
df.combine_first(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(people).T)

End result
         age    city
jon     20.0    foo
peter   30.0    foo


Load your dict into a pandas DataFrame and append it to your existing data:
import io
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'city': {'jon': 'foo', 'peter': 'foo'}, 'age': {}})
age_json = json.dumps(people)
age_data = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(age_json), orient='index')

yields
>>> df
      city  age
jon    foo  NaN
peter  foo  NaN
>>> age_data
       age
jon     20
peter   30

Now add the age data into the main data frame (which overwrites the existing column):
df.age = age_data

which gives:
>>> df
      city  age
jon    foo   20
peter  foo   30

